# Is it possible in sequelize to query based on an association?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I modelled a data structure where I have a n:m relation between "Rooms" and "Users".

Now I want to delete / destroy a room.
Therefore I want to check if the deleting user is in the room.

I have the username and the roomid.

How can I accomplisch that in **one** Query.
Basically my question is of it possible to do something like that in a query:

```
Room.destroy({
   where: {
       //username in users
       users: {$contains: { username: "some username" }}
   }
})
```

Here users is an "Association" to my users.

Comment: How is it declared your models associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your users model is defined as `User`,
this may helps you (or at least gives you a start point):

```js
Room.destroy({
  include: [{
    model: User,
      through: {
        where: {username: "some username"}
      }
  }]
});
```

This is described in the n:m querying section in [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations):

> With Belongs-To-Many you can query based on **through** relation and
>   select specific attributes. For example using findAll with **through**
>
> ```
> User.findAll({
>   include: [{
>     model: Project,
>       through: {
>         attributes: ['createdAt', 'startedAt', 'finishedAt']
>           where: {completed: true}
>       }
>   }]
> });
> ```